# Reset radio group within a table which is in a tr

Tags: jquery, dynamic, radio-button, html-table

I can reset all radio buttons over many rows with the following jQuery.

```
$( ".reset_location" ).click(function() {
    $('#tbl_outside table.tbl_Inside input:radio').each(function(){
            $(this).attr("checked", false);
    });
    $('#tbl_outside table.tbl_Inside input:radio').effect("pulsate");
});
```

What I need to do is if the user clicks on the `reset_location radio (class=reset_location)` then set the attr to checked false for the radios in `tbl_Inside` on that row (not all the rows).

Hope you can help?

```
<table id="tbl_outside">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td> Location </td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1194">
    <td>
          <input type="radio" value="reset" class="reset_location"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table class="tbl_Inside" id="93cf9d8ba8" >
        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                   <input type="radio" value="h" name="93cf9d8ba8"/>
              </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>
                   <input type="radio" value="l" name="93cf9d8ba8"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="c" name="93cf9d8ba8"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="r" name="93cf9d8ba8"/>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
              <input type="radio" value="f" name="93cf9d8ba8"/>
              </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1193">
    <td>
          <input type="radio" value="reset" class="reset_location"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table class="tbl_Inside" id="123456" >
        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                   <input type="radio" value="h" name="123456"/>
              </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>
                   <input type="radio" value="l" name="123456"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="c" name="123456"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="r" name="123456"/>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
              <input type="radio" value="f" name="123456"/>
              </td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the parent `<tr>` element, and select all `input[type="radio"]` elements. Unless you're using an old version of jQuery, you should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to set a property.

```
$( ".reset_location" ).click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr:first').find(':radio')
        .prop("checked", false)
        .effect("pulsate");
});
```

Comment: You'll need to use `parents` or `closest` rather than `parent` because the parent of `this` is the `td`. Also, this will uncheck the `.reset_location` radio as well as those in `.tbl_Inside`, which is not what the OP does in the example (although I think that is what should probably happen). So +1 from me.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Thanks, I missed the `s`. I've used `parents('tr:first')` to select the first, closest row, in case of a nested table.

Comment: Rob W that's not working.  The radios are in tbl_Inside which is in a td on the row.

Comment: @Rob My suggested code does: `Go to the CURRENT row  >  Select ALL radio inputs in the row  >  check them  +  pulsate effect`. What's missing?

Comment: @Rob W  Current row then we need to find the td that contains tbl_Inside. The radios are in that table which is in a td.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Rob - `find` will search all descendants of the selected `tr`. That includes the `tbl_Inside` element, and the radio buttons which are inside that. It should find the right radio buttons.

Comment: @Rob I believe that you don't know the meaning of `this`; `this` inside the event listener of `.reset_location` points to the clicked input element. So, `$(this).parents('tr:first')` selects the "current active" row.

Comment: @Rob W. I understand that it selected the current row.  But the radio group is in a table which is in a cell on that row.  All five radio buttons are in there own table (tbl_Inside) and your selector suggestion is not finding them.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Rob `.find(':radio')` returns EVERY `<input type="radio">` of the current row. Since your table, `.tbl_inside` is a child of the current row, all input elements inside this row are also selected.

Comment: @Rob W.  Thanks!  Got it to work. Had a typo when I moved your code over. Doh!  Again all thanks!